# Scheduling an application action in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, silverlight, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a WPF media application for running audio files using Media Element.
I succeeded in it . But i want to schedule playing a songs which i selected in some interval of time repeatedly. Say 10'o clock in every day or in every hour etc..

What is the best way to do that ?

Initially am think about doing it using a Timer.  But that makes my code complex because i have to play multiple songs in different intervals set by user.

Recently i go to know about [Task Scheduler](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) and i run their sample code [open a notepad] and it works perfectly.

```
  using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
  {
     // Create a new task definition and assign properties
     TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
     td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

     // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
     td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

     // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
     td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

     // Register the task in the root folder
     ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

     // Remove the task we just created
     ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
  }
```

How do i define an action which play a song on this context ? Currently they are providing ExecAction,SendEmail,ShowMessage and ComHandlerAction [see this link](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ActionSamples&referringTitle=Examples)

Or Can we invoke play method of my application by this Task Scheduler? Please help me by providing any idea .

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you would need to order your collection of times with the closest time first. Then, you would only need one `DispatcherTimer` and you could set its `Interval` value to the length of time between now and the first time from your collection:

```
private DispatcherTimer mediaPlayerTimer = null;
```

...

```
mediaPlayerTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
mediaPlayerTimer.Interval = YourFirstDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
mediaPlayerTimer.Tick += MediaPlayerTimer_Tick;
mediaPlayerTimer.Start();
```

...

```
private void MediaPlayerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mediaPlayerTimer.Stop();
    // Load next audio file and play
    // Remove YourFirstDateTime from your collection
    // Set YourFirstDateTime = the next item from the collection
    mediaPlayerTimer.Interval = YourFirstDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
    mediaPlayerTimer.Start();
}
```